# Using usecols and skiprows at the same time (in Pandas read_csv) gives error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using read_csv in Pandas v0.18.1 to read in some data. I want to choose a subset of columns and rows from the csv, so I have tried:

```
df_a = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col = False, usecols=cols_to_use, skiprows=1)
```

This gives me a *ValueError: Usecols do not match names.*
Note that cols_to_use is a list of column names, but if I leave out the skiprows part:

```
df_a = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col = False, usecols=cols_to_use)
```

it works fine, and similarly if I leave out the usecols bit and put skiprows back in, that works fine too.

Could this be a bug (that you can't use usecols and skiprows at the same time)? I've tried looking in the documentation but couldn't find any mention of it. Or perhaps there is a logical reason that you can't use both?

(Also if there is a better/more obvious way of picking out a subset of columns and rows from a csv that would be appreciated too!)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  But `cols_to_use` can be a list of column names if those column names are in a header row (which you might be skipping with `skiprows=1`) or a list of integers.  Maybe you are trying to name your columns.  In that case you want `names=cols_to_use`.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the file you are trying to read? And could you provide the output of the working commands?
My guess is that your file has the column names in the first row. If you use skiprows pandas might not read the first row and might read the column names from row 2.

Comment: The question states he wants to "picking out a subset of columns and rows from a csv". So it seems like `names=cols_to_use` is not the way to go.

Comment: If you want to skip specific rows you can provide the row number as a list using e.g. `skiprows=[1]`. The line numbers are 0-indexed, hence the first line has index 0.

Comment: Ah of course, thank you - using skiprows=1 was a bad example for me to try out since it skipped my headings. I tried it with skiprows=[5] and it works now.

Comment: Glad I could help. Still, it would have been helpfull to provide a fully working minimal example that shows the structure of your csv file and the output of the working commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first row of your csv file contains the column names then `skiprows=1` will ignore the row with the column names and you run into the error.

If you want to skip specific rows you can provide the row numbers as a list using e.g. `skiprows=[1]`. The line numbers are 0-indexed, hence the column names are in line 0 and the first data line is number 1.

Comment: I believe if you add the names of all the columns to `names`, you should be able to use `usecols`